# How to Render a Grid of Cards in flutter WEB , with Images on it . Like youtube

Tags: flutter, flutter-web-browser, flutter-web3

I am trying to make a grid of cards , that are containing images in it . I am not using Image.network() to load the images as it don't directly work in flutter web . So i am using a package called as [image_network](https://pub.dev/packages/image_network) from pub dev . But doing this is making the UX very bad . The Ui is totally lagging due to loading of image.

Here is the error , what flutter is showing  :

```
Flutter was unable to create enough overlay surfaces. This is usually caused by too many platform views being displayed at once.
You may experience incorrect rendering.
```

Link to the demo video of the same : [text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ijcQ1NL-hqKND80zVGQfVXoYd2CCcTB_/view?usp=drive_link)

I am expecting to have a grid view of card , that have images , that are loaded at the runtime from the internet .
Something like youtube.